# pandas: combine text from rows

Tags: python, pandas

From the following dataframe;

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'Section':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'Sub':['What','is','this?','I','am','not','sure.']})
```

How do I get a result similar to this;

```
['What is this?','I am not sure.']
```

So far I've only been able to come up with a `groupby` like this;

```
for d in data1.groupby(['Section'])['Sub']:
    print d[1]
```

which gives you something like this;

```
0     What
1       is
2    this?
Name: Sub, dtype: object
3        I
4       am
5      not
6    sure.
Name: Sub, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` the items with space:

```
In [34]: for d in data1.groupby(['Section'])['Sub']:
    ...:     print ' '.join(d[1])
What is this?
I am not sure.
```

and to make them a list:

```
In [35]: [' '.join(d[1]) for d in data1.groupby(['Section'])['Sub']]
Out[35]: ['What is this?', 'I am not sure.']
```

Comment: @richie np, glad to help ;)